# Categorical Variables in Random Forests

Tags: modeling, random-forest, categorical-encoding

I am aware that categorical variables should be one hot encoded before modeling with random Forests. But I am not entirely sure why.

Lets say we have a predictor categorical variable with 7 levels. The tree should be able to find similarities/differences within this variable if it is numerically encoded. Why do we have to one hot encode categorical variables?

How can I simulate a regression to showcase the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the decision tree construction within the random forest. When constructing a DT one selects for all (numeric) attributes all possible (actually  seen) values $x$ of that attribute such that making the decision

$$
     value < x
$$

will generate the most information gain, for all combinations of attributes and values.

If the attribute is categorical, the decision would have to be

$$
    value \in subset
$$

But that would require an exponential search for all possible subsets of the attribute, which makes the algorithm much less usable.